# React router-dom <Link> to pass multiple params and access them using useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

I am passing in multiple params like so:

```
<Link to={`/tech/${data.foo}${data.bar}`}>{data.you}</Link>
```

I try to access my params passed using useParams like this:

```
let { foo } = useParams<{foo:string}>();
let { bar } = useParams<{bar:string}>();
```

I can access foo, but bar says undefined if I console.log it.
But if I do this:

```
<Link to={`/tech/${data.bar}/${data.foo}`}>{data.you}</Link>
```

I then have access to data.bar but not data._foo

```
<div>{foo}</div>
<div>{bar}</div>
```

Does anyone know how to properly write this so I can pass 2 params and access both of them using useParams like I am trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: How did you define the Route?

Comment: The component that uses `useParams` is a child of a `Route` component from `react-router-dom`. How do you define that `Route`? That's where the params are defined and may be the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-link-params-cf033?file=/src/App.js) passing multiple parameters is possible as long as you define the `Route` properly.

```js
<Route path="/page/:foo/:bar" component={Page} />
```

You must define a parameter for both pieces using the `:`.

Then accessing like `const { foo, bar } = useParams();` will work. You may also keep them on separate lines like you had in your question, but this way is more concise.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but does not show me how to use <Link> to pass multiple params. I do not want to use <Route>. My component is an array of data types and foo and bar are inside of it like I said I am able to access both params individually, but not able to pass them both in and access them both using<Link>

Comment: If you're not using a `Route`, you're not using react router correctly. You can't just use `Link` by itself. It will not work.