# Undefined value from Link input state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am currently trying to pass some information through React-Router-DOM's Link component to another one of my components in which I tried this:

```
export default function Test() {

      return(
          <div>
             <Link to={{ pathname: './NewPage', state: { testValue: true }}}>New Page</Link>
          </div>
      )
}
```

```
export default function NewPage(props) {

     console.log(props.location.state)

     return(
       <div>
         {props.location.state}
       </div>
      )

}
```

The error says: **Cannot read property 'state' of undefined** at the console.log(props.location.state) line

Note: I am using React Hooks not class

Comment: How are you using `NewPage`? It's important to note that the issue is that `props.location` is not defined. We can't tell if the state is passed correctly until you actually have access to the `location` prop from react-router.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895445/9381601) with a running example may help.

Comment: I wish to use the values in the state to calculate some new values in NewPage then return those to the DOM

Comment: I mean "how" as in where you actually use it. Like your Route

Comment: I am sorry I am confused by what you mean? I was under the assumption that once  the end-user clicks on the Link defined inside the Test function it would redirect to the NewPage?

Comment: There's no correlation between the `pathname` and the component name. It's just convention that gives them the same name. You have to actually tell React to render it somehow. Are you using a framework?

Comment: Oh, I already created the the route for NewPage using React-Router-DOM by using the Route component: ```<Route exact path='/NewPage' component = {() = <NewPage />}/>```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm looking for, and that's your problem. I'll write an answer here in a minute to show you why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) that react-router allows you to use must be passed into your component somehow. There are several patterns for accomplishing this, a HOC ([`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)), a [hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks), or by having [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) pass them in directly by passing it a `component` prop.

Notice how you instantiate the `NextPage` component

```js
<Route exact path='/NewPage' component={() => <NewPage />}/>
```

It is given **no props**.

The [`component`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) prop is intended to be passed a *reference* to a component. You have provided an anonymous function in order to satisfy this requirement, but you lose the react-router props because of it. In order to get them you would need to pass them along `(props) => <NewPage {...props}/>` (But *please* don't do that, use [`render`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) if you really want to use a function).

Simply cut out the arrow function and give the `component` prop the component reference, and it will get the rout props it needs:

```js
<Route exact path='/NewPage' component={NewPage}/>
```

---

Since you're using functional components, I would recommend rendering your components as `Route` children, and using the hooks to access the react-router values.

```js
<Route exact path='/NewPage'>
  <NewPage />
</Route>

....

export default function NewPage(props) {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      {location.state}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This syntax allows you to easily add other props that you may need to `NewPage`, while still being able to use the route props through hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `search` or `hash` rather than `state` as i'm guessing you want your data to persist; https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

```
<Link
  to={{
  pathname: "/courses",
  search: "?sort=name",
  hash: "#the-hash",
 }}
/>
```

and then you can access it just the way you did in using `props.location.search` or `props.location.hash`
you can refer to the docs to confirm the properties https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location