# Pass object one page to another page using Link in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass object one page to another page. According to requirement, I need to do it using "Link" tag. this is my code.

1st page is as below

```
<Link  
        to={{
          pathname: "/2ndPage",
          state: { foo: 'bar'} 
        }}
      > Action</Link>
```

When I click this button, I need to pass object to my second page. this is my second page code that I tried

```
function 2ndPage(props) {
console.log(props)
  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
}
```

correctly project build successfully. When I click my first page button, page is redirect correctly. But object did not pass. I think this is wrong approach. can u help me to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined value from Link input state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114478/undefined-value-from-link-input-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, start the function name with a number it's just a little unconventional.

The `foo` value should be located in `location.state`

Try this

```
import { useParams} from "react-router-dom";

function TwoNdPage(props){
  let { foo } = useParams(); 
//const {foo} = props.location.state // or you can try this
  console.log(foo) // it should return bar
  return <h2>About</h2>
}
export default TwoNdPage;
```

[image: Edit React Router (forked)]

Comment: now error said,TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'foo' of 'props.location.state' as it is undefined.

Comment: @Kumara it looks like the props are undefined something wrong with the structure. can you please share more codes?

Comment: @Kumara I just did a quick CodeSandBox shows how to structure it

Comment: Is it possible to use `router.query` instead of `props.location`?

Comment: @VicenteC I think this is an old way maybe in version 2 of react-router

Comment: @Shrroy thanks for the sample. but still error in my code. any way i will check it. thanks,

Comment: @Kumara you're welcome! if it's possible to provide more codes so I can help you better.

Comment: @Shrroy fixed the issue. Its my mistake. pathname should change to as below
pathname: "app/2ndPage", now passed correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your state will be on location object `location.state`. You can use hook for location `useLocation` inside SecondPage component. Attention location.state can be undefined if you open link directly but it has to be present after click on link.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const SecondPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <p>{location.state}</p>
  );
};
```